# Usage of peak-to-peak voltage and RMS voltage

Tags: ac, measurement, voltage-measurement, rms

Why are RMS values and peak-to-peak voltages common in use? For example RMS voltages in the context of noise. I see especially for peak-to-peak voltage no practical usage. Why should I need more voltage values than the amplitude of an AC signal amplitude, for example?

Comment: What exactly does this mean: "...practical usage instead of using the amplitude of an ac signal amplitude for example."?

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my question.

Comment: You can't always assume that the AC signal (as in non-DC, not sinusoidal) is sinusoidal for one. A bipolar signal full of thin rectangles might have the same peak to peak as a sine-wave but have a very different area under the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For different wave shapes, there is a conversion constant for sine, square, pulse, triangle, half rectified sine, full rectified sine.

But ADC's use Sample & Hold and are fast, while some ADC's use dual integration (up/\dn) to reduce noise in the result, but are slower but useful for DC.

- some measure in signal Peak voltage and assume sine and convert to RMS
- so you must know assumptions of shape and conversion for accuracy
- RF "true RMS power" RMS is measured by heat rise precisely.
- DMM's with "true RMS" compute root mean squared of many samples
- RF carrier signal often in uV or dBuV or dBmV or in power 0dBm = 0 mW average in standard R (=75 for video, 50 ohms for most all others) These are often peak measurements in RF Rx from AGC circuit (RSSI receive signal strength indicator) and converted to dBm average power.

  ### common measurements
- Vp, Peak   (generated)
- Vpp, Peak-to-Peak (without DC)
- Vrms, using RMS meter or calculated by factors

  - to compute power Vrms*Irms = Pavg = Vrms^2/R
  - average power of 1 to N cycles
  - otherwise V(t)*I(t)=P(t)
- Signal/Noise Ratio SNR or S/N
- SNR RMS ratio in voltage or power
- SNR ratio is same if sig. and noise are both same shape.
- for SNR measurements both RMS and peak ratios are used  for estimating error rates depending on noise characteristics random impulse vs random white noise . This SNR is used to predict bit error rates (BER).
- Peak/Average current = "crest factor" diode/cap\load
  RMS current for Capacitor power dissipation (e-caps)

Answer (score 2):

RMS voltage (or current) allows you to calculate the power that would flow into a constant amd known resistance load. It's useful for calculations of signal to noise power ratios as well as heating effects.

It's not particularly useful for determining the voltage rating  you need for a diode (**Peak** Inverse Voltage), for example, or predicting when an amplifier will clip the signal.

There is only a fixed ratio between RMS and peak or peak-to-peak for known types of waveforms (the \$\sqrt{2}\$ factor for peak of a sinusoidal wave or the 1.0 factor for DC, for example), so having one without the other is not necessarily sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

RMS value is useful for power calculations. Usually with continuous sine waves such as with power grid you only see the RMS values. Any custom designs need to withstand the peak value.

You might also be measuring a non-continous wave e.g. from a sensor and the peak value might be what you are looking for.